# Extract value in dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have this dict:

```
data = {'name':['Andrea', 'Luca'], 'age':['14', '15']}
```

I write:

```
for key, value in data.items():
    print (key, value)
```

here in this my results in (print(key, value)) are:

```
name ['Andrea', 'Luca']
age ['14', '15']
```

I would like to extract this:

```
name = Andrea
name = Luca
age = 14
age = 15
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value` is your list. Iterate through it and print each item.

```
for key, value in data.items():
    for x in value:
        print('{} = {}'.format(key, x))
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add an inner `for` loop:

```
for key, value in data.items():
    for subvalue in value:
        print(key, subvalue)

name Andrea
name Luca
age 14
age 15
```